# Can't install amdgpu-pro 18.40 on Ubuntu Server 18.04.01

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-sources, amdgpu-pro

I posted [this question](https://community.amd.com/thread/233867) on the AMD community forums, but decided to also post it here as it seemed relevant to Ubuntu.

> I seem to be having issues installing the latest driver on Ubuntu Server. I've installed amdgpu-pro 18.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 in the past but I can't at all get the amdgpu-pro 18.40-676022 driver (Download Not Complete | AMD from Radeon™ Software for Linux® 18.40 Highlights | AMD ) to install on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04.1. I've downloaded the driver twice and verified that both had the same SHA256 checksums (is there an official repository of the driver checksums?)
>
> It works neither on its own nor with flags
>
> ```
> $ ./amdgpu-pro-install
> deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
> Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
> Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
> Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
> Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
> Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
> Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
> Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
> Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
> Fetched 172 kB in 4s (45.3 kB/s)
> Reading package lists... Done
> Package: *amdgpu*
> Pin: release o=AMD
> Pin: version *-676022
> Pin-Priority: 1000
>
> Package: *amdgpu*:i386
> Pin: release o=AMD
> Pin: version *-676022
> Pin-Priority: 1000
>
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> amdgpu : Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers (= 1:18.1.0-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers (= 1:18.1.0-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: gst-omx-amdgpu (= 1.0.0.1-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.92-676022)
> Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.92-676022)
> Depends: libllvm6.0-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:6.0-676022)
> Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (= 1.14.0-676022)
> Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (= 1.14.0-676022)
> Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.1.0-676022)
> amdgpu-pro-lib32 : Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (= 18.40-676022)
> Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 18.40-676022)
> Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 18.40-676022)
> Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (= 18.40-676022)
> Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 18.40-676022)
> vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
> Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:3.3.1) but it is not installable
> Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.8) but it is not installable
> Depends: wsa-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

---

> ```
> $ ./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy --headless
> deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
> Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
> Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
> Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
> Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
> Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
> Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
> Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
> Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
> Fetched 172 kB in 5s (32.7 kB/s)
> Reading package lists... Done
> Package: *amdgpu*
> Pin: release o=AMD
> Pin: version *-676022
> Pin-Priority: 1000
> Package: *amdgpu*:i386
> Pin: release o=AMD
> Pin: version *-676022
> Pin-Priority: 1000
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> amdgpu : Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers (= 1:18.1.0-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers (= 1:18.1.0-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: gst-omx-amdgpu (= 1.0.0.1-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

---

> I've also tried upgrading the 18.2 driver to 18.4 on the ubuntu server 18.04 and that caused issues and now I cant even uninstall amdgpu-pro on the 18.04 server to downgrade to 18.2

---

> ```
> $ amdgpu-pro-uninstall
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core (= 18.40-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-common (= 1.0.0-676022) but it is not going to be installed
> amdgpu-dkms : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> amdgpu-pro-core : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> glamor-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> gst-omx-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> ids-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-common but it is not going to be installed
> libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-common:i386
> libdrm2-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> libegl1-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> libgbm1-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 but it is not installable or
> libtxc-dxtn0 but it is not installable
> libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but it is not installable or
> libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
> libglapi-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> libllvm6.0-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libllvm6.0-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> libwayland-amdgpu-client0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> libwayland-amdgpu-server0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> wsa-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
> wsa-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
> ```

---

> ```
> $ sudo apt --fix-broken install
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Correcting dependencies... Done
> The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
> ids-amdgpu
> Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
> The following additional packages will be installed:
> libdrm-amdgpu-common
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> libdrm-amdgpu-common
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 184 not upgraded.
> 64 not fully installed or removed.
> Need to get 0 B/6,736 B of archives.
> After this operation, 28.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
> Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm-amdgpu-common 1.0.0-676022 [6,736 B]
> (Reading database ... 114143 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu-common_1.0.0-676022_all.deb ...
> Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-common (1.0.0-676022) ...
> dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libdrm-amdgpu-common_1.0.0-676022_all.deb (--unpack):
> trying to overwrite '/opt/amdgpu/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package ids-amdgpu 1.0.0-606296
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libdrm-amdgpu-common_1.0.0-676022_all.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```

---

> ```
> $ sudo apt remove amdgpu*
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu_18.40-676022_amd64.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu_18.40-676022_i386.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu_18.40-676022_i386.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu_18.40-676022_i386.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-core_18.40-676022_all.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-core_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-core_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-dkms_18.40-676022_all.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-dkms_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-dkms_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-doc_18.40-676022_all.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-doc_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-doc_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-install
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-lib32_18.40-676022_amd64.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-lib32_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-lib32_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro_18.40-676022_amd64.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-pro_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-pro_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro_18.40-676022_i386.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-pro_18.40-676022_i386.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-pro_18.40-676022_i386.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-core_18.40-676022_all.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-pro-core_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-pro-core_18.40-676022_all.deb'
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-install
> E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-lib32_18.40-676022_amd64.deb
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'amdgpu-pro-lib32_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'amdgpu-pro-lib32_18.40-676022_amd64.deb'https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-18.40-676022-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
> ```
>
> I tried installing the `amdgpu-pro-18.20-606296` driver on Ubuntu Server 18.04.01 and I seem to have gotten the same error messages. Maybe this is an issue with ubuntu repositories or something.
>
> I tried installing the AMD 18.40 driver in a virtual machine (Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1, Ubuntu desktop 16.04.5, Ubuntu Server 16.04.5, Ubuntu Server 18.04.1)
>
> - Desktop 18: seemed to install but gave an error:

`WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel` (assuming this has something to do with the virtual machine)

> - Desktop 16: same as Desktop 18
> - Server 16: seemed to install without issue
> - Server 18: same issues as above, also tried with AMD drivers 18.20 and 18.30 and none worked, all gave `Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers ... but it is not going to be installed` I tried installing the package manually which led to
>
>   ```
>   Depends: libval1-amdgpu ...
>   Package 'libva1-amdgpu' has no installation candidate
>   ```
>
> So I'm guessing this is an issue specific to Server 18.04.1 and not Ubuntu 18.04.1 in general since it seems to install fine in Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1.
>
> I tried changing the mirror in the server 18.04.1 installation from `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` to `http://ao.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` since that's the mirror desktop seems to be using but that didn't seem to do anything.
>
> Confirmed working on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1. I installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1 onto a flash drive and was able to install amd-gpu-pro 18.40 and successfully run it with an RX 470.
>
> Still won't install on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 and I still have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

The question was answered in [this thread](https://community.amd.com/thread/233867) on AMD Community by [jgrevich](https://community.amd.com/people/jgrevich).

> Out of the box 18.04 doesn't have those packages. Try adding the universe apt repo:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository universe
> ```

Comment: And OP confirmed it to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For those who couldn't install by adding universe repo can try

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

As the dependencies are i386. I do not know what other problems this can create especially when you install other packages later - so use it at your own risk.