# AMD GPU Driver install failure 18.04.2

Tags: drivers, apt, amd-graphics

Trying to install my new Radeon VII on 18.04.2 Bionic I am running into a wall. Trying to uninstall and re-install doesn't make a difference. Anyone know a way around this?

Attempting to run the installer I see this:

```
nas:~/amdgpu-pro-18.50-725072-ubuntu-18.04$ ./amdgpu-install 
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg                                                                                                                        
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg                                                                                               
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
amdgpu-pro-pin is already the newest version (18.50-725072).
Selected version '18.50-725072' (localhost [all]) for 'amdgpu-pro-pin'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.95-725072)
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.95-725072)
                Depends: libllvm7.0-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:7.0-725072)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (= 1.15.0-725072)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (= 1.15.0-725072)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 (= 1.15.0-725072)
                Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-725072)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I have no held packages. dpkg --get-selections | grep hold yields nothing

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097030/cant-install-amdgpu-pro-18-40-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-01 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107272/installing-amdgpu-18-50-for-ubuntu-18-04-resulting-in-dependency-issues

Comment: @Guser314 thats already enabled. I think the error is happening somewhere here in the script. `[[ "${OPTIONS[*]}" =~ "pro" ]] \
  && pro_meta_packages=($OPENGL_META_PACKAGE \
    $VULKAN_META_PACKAGE \
    $LIB32_OPENGL_META_PACKAGE \
    $LIB32_VULKAN_META_PACKAGE)`

Comment: I see now says clearly in Hit:6-9 repos enabled. I just installed 18.50-708488 again on 18.04.2. I see you have a newer version at 18.50-725072 which is interesting. All packages get moved to /opt/amdgpu-pro-local before use, they all make it, still there? I diff'd the installer for your version and mine and only install options are different (--px is deprecated in 18.50-725072). Not sure much help, sorry.

Comment: No problem :D I think I got it working. I ran `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` before ./amdgpu-install

Comment: I'll have to figure out why I didn't have to do that explicitly. I see I too have i386: `cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch\  amd64\ i386`